# Libgdx- Resetting a Vector3 to use it multiple times in different situations

Tags: libgdx, vectorization

OK guys I need your help,

I'm trying to figure out how to reset a Vector3, to use it on multiple situations,...

For example I got a code where for testing purpose I have several buttons,
Where the first one uses a Matrix4 that refers to a Vector3 to translate a player,

How would I go to do so:
Button 1 pressed

```
Vector3: 1,2,3
```

Button 2 pressed

```
Vector3: reset,  new values 2,4,6
```

Pseudo code for comprehension..

Can't seem to find a correct way to do so,
Not behind the computer right now,
Code will come in time,

Maybe if else if can do the trick but not sure :3

Any hint?

for reference, edited qn:

```
 stage.addActor(tpS);
        ghost = new Matrix4();
        tpIleApprentis.addListener((new InputListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                TpS.hide();
                translation = new Vector3(86.83f,96f,63.5f);
                ghost.getTranslation(translation);
                translation.set(0,0,0);
                PlayerSystem.characterComponent.ghostObject.setWorldTransform(ghost);
                return false;
            }
        }));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to "reset" the Vector3 before reusing it, you can simply override it with new values using one of the set methods.

https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Vector3.html#set-float-float-float-

```
Vector3 vector = new Vector3(1, 2, 3);
...
vector.set(2, 4, 6); // reuse
```

Comment: first of all thanks thought, this answer was implicit,  but everytime I try to translate a player from one position to another,  it constantly uses the first created vector,  even if i asign other values to it,  if I firstly use vector 1,2,3 and then assign new values to it before reusing it such as 2,4,6; it will instead of use the newly created values, use the old ones.

Comment: It sounds like you might be updating a different vector, maybe you have made a copy of the vector somehow and are updating the copy instead of updating the original. Try a simple test by creating a new vector, print its values, then update the vector and print its values again. The second print statement should be the new values and not the original values.

Comment: Hi,  already did this test,  newer value was printed but not used as it should, strange tho

Comment: If the print statement is correct then something else is causing the problem and not the Vector3. Can you edit your original question and add your code? That will help us to figure out where the problem is.

Comment: Frankly don't know, the first translate method do the trick, the second one that should set new values to the vector do it's job but never translate the player where it should be translated, anyway, puted that away from now on, gonna think of it and work on something other, oopsy, dunno really how, and artemis doc won't really help :/
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61449095/libgdx-how-to-switch-from-ashley-engine-to-artemis-ones
An anwser to this one would help much more ^^'

@Tekkerue did that edit tough

Comment: I do not use the physics engines myself so I can't tell you what is going wrong there. But you are setting the Vector3 correctly and there is something else wrong with your player translation. Maybe you can repost your question asking how to translate the player in the physics engine you are using (is that Bullet?) and someone with experience in that area should be able to help you.

Comment: Yep, I do used bullet for that purpose, I go naturally no experience on either sides, but i try to gain some, experiencing threw coding as a hobby, anyway thanks for answering bro!

Comment: You're welcome. You should be able to get help with your problem if you re-post your question in terms of "How to translate a player with Bullet in LibGDX" (or something like that). Include your code and use the Bullet and LibGDX tags in your question. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so,
as I was working with Ashley ECS and Bullet System,
I finally ended up using such method that basically remove the player and recreate the player,
Yes the solution isn't optimal, but it works,
Actually it's plenty sufficient:

```
tpIleApprentis0.addListener(new InputListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            gameWorld.remove(gameWorld.character);
            gameWorld.remove(gameWorld.characterHair);
            gameWorld.remove(gameWorld.characterEar);
            gameWorld.remove(gameWorld.characterScar);
            gameWorld.remove(gameWorld.characterMouth);
            System.out.println("Teleportation Ville des Apprentis");
            gameWorld.createPlayer(86.8f,64.4f,-96.6f);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Ashley engine is created and located in gameworld class;
remove method is part of ashley ecs system and involves bullet component
for the create method it's the same:

```
public void remove(Entity entity)
{
    engine.removeEntity(entity);
    bulletSystem.removeBody(entity);
}

public void createPlayer(float x, float y, float z)
{
    character = playerFactory.createMaleCharacter(bulletSystem, x, y, z);
    characterHair = playerFactory.createMaleHair(x, y, z);
    characterEar = playerFactory.createMaleEar(x, y, z);
    characterMouth = playerFactory.createMaleMouth(x, y, z);
    characterScar = playerFactory.createMaleScar(x, y, z);
    engine.addEntity(character);
    engine.addEntity(characterHair);
    engine.addEntity(characterEar);
    engine.addEntity(characterMouth);
    engine.addEntity(characterScar);
```

...

if anybody got a better solution?
but as said, actually this solution fits my needs